# Why my Spring redis cache doesn't work even with anntations

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis, spring-cache

I follow the instructions on this tutorial (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-redis-cache)

```
@Cacheable(value = "itemCache")
public UserInfo getUserInfo(String id) {
    // without explicit manipulate cache, the value can't be retrieved from Redis
    UserInfo res = cacheManager.getCache("itemCache").get(id, UserInfo.class);
    if (res != null) {
        return res;
    }
    try {
            ... retrieve from database ...
            res = convertMapToUserInfo(id, userInfoMap);
            // without explicit manipulate cache, the value can't be stored in Redis
            cacheManager.getCache("itemCache").put(id, res);
            return res;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    } finally {
        ...
    }
    return null;
}
```

The weird thing is, I have to put/get items from Cache manualy, even I use Cacheable annotation. Without explicit manipulate cache, the returned value of getUserInfo can't be cached.

The RedisConfiguration contains code

```
@Bean
public RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer redisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer() {
    return (builder) -> builder
            .withCacheConfiguration("itemCache",
                    this.cacheConfiguration());

}

@Bean
public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration() {
    return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .disableCachingNullValues()
            .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));
}
```

And I also add @EnableCaching to my Application class. Could anyone help me figure out why my cache doesn't take effect. Thanks!

Comment: If it doesn't work, you haven't followed the instructions but deviated somewhere. Also how is thus `getUserInfo` called (if it is called from within the same class it won't work). Finally make sure you have `@EnableCaching` else it won;t work either and that all packages are properly scanned. Or in short add your `@SpringBootApplication` annotatated class **and** include the `package` statement of your classes (or at least show your package structure).

Answer (score 0):

I've recently found out that if we use just one entry with the builder it does'nt work. But if you have more than one cache in your project and include all these entries in this method or even if you add a 'dummy' entry, it works. Maybe a bug or a known issue in Spring implementation, I don't know.

```
@Bean
public RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer redisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer() {
  return (builder) -> builder
    .withCacheConfiguration("itemCache", this.cacheConfiguration())
    .withCacheConfiguration("dummy", this.cacheConfiguration());
}
```

I hope helps.